# Opencart pass variable from controller to model

Tags: php, ajax, model, controller, opencart

(hi) everyone!

I'm using OpenCart v.2.2.

First I have a trouble with PHP Event Calendar, which I try to develop.

So, my question to you is how can I pass data variable from controller to model where this variable is set in SQL query?

I will show some piece of code.

Model:

```
<?php 
$year = '';
$month = '';
$dateYear = ($year != '') ? $year : date("Y");
$dateMonth = ($month != '') ? $month : date("m");
...
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE event_start = '" . $currentDate . "' AND status = 1");
$event_num = $result->num_rows;

?>
```

So, when I choose from dropdown any month or year

```
<select name="month_dropdown" class="month_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo $get_months; ?></select>
<select name="year_dropdown" class="year_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo $get_years; ?></select>
```

I just want to get selected month or/and year and then pass the value to controller. After this the data should be passed to model to set selected month. If I choose 10th month then

Model:

```
<?php
$month = '10';
?>
```

I tried to pass the variable hardcode, but there is no result in the model :(

Controller:

```
<?php
$data['month'] = '10';
$data['year'] = '2017';
?>
```

Model:

```
<?php 
if (isset($data['month'])) {
   $month = $data['month'];
}
if (isset($data['year'])) {
   $year= $data['year'];
}
?>
```

But I got the following notice:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\events\catalog\model\event_calendar\event.php on line 11
```

But when I hardcode the model $month = '10' I get successful all of days for this month.

Thanks in advance for all replies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below :

View (.tpl file)

```
<select name="month_dropdown"><?php echo $your_varialbe; ?></select>
```

Controller file

```
if(isset($this->request->post['month_dropdown'])) {
$month_dropdown = $this->request->post['month_dropdown'];
} else {
$month_dropdown = 0;
}
$info = $this->model_catalog_product->your_method_name($month_dropdown);
```

Model file (assuming you are using model - catalog/model/catalog/product.php)

```
public function your_method_name($your_method_name) {
//use $your_method_name here 
}
```

Hope this help you.